# PDEs: subsequence converges to solution, so whole sequence does too

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, partial-differential-equations

Suppose we want existence of a function $u$ for the PDE
$$\left(\frac{d}{dt}u,v\right) = b(u,v)$$
for all $v$ in a test space.

Sometimes in PDE you have use a Galerkin approximation, so say $u_n$ is a sequence that solves a PDE
$$\left(\frac{d}{dt}u_n,v\right) = b(u_n,v)$$
and you show that a subsequence $u_{n_k}$ converges to something (say $u$), and that $u$ solves the original PDE.

My question is: how does one get from this subsequence convering to $u$ to saying "the whole sequence converges to $u$"?

Comment: Once we pass the limit from the Galerkin approximation subsequence $\{u_{n_k}\}$ to that $u$ in order to prove $u$ is the weak solution, $\{u_n\}$'s mission accomplished, duty fulfilled, we do not need it anymore for the existence is proved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often, you have the following situation: You have a sequence $\{u_k\}$ and you can show that every subsequence $\{u_{n_k}\}$ has a subsequence $\{u_{n_{k_i}}\}$ converging towards $u$.

Now, you can prove by contradiction that indeed the whole sequence $\{u_k\}$ converges towards $u$: Assume, that $\{u_k\}$ does not converge towards $u$. Then, there is a $\varepsilon > 0$ and a subsequence $\{u_k\}$ with $\lVert u_k - u\rVert \ge \varepsilon$. However, this contradicts the existence of a convergent subsequence of $\{u_k\}$.

The same argument can be used for weak convergence (and convergence w.r.t. other topologies).